# Which python... file directory PIP

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pip

I am sure on my Mac 0SX 10.9 I have more than one version of Python 2.7.5.

When I type in

```
which python
```

in the terminal, I get /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

When I am doing a pip.install it seems those are loading in a different path, they are all under /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages.

When I am in IDLE or my IDE (Sypder) and type

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

I get lots and lots of paths that start with /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages.

My problem is when I do a help() or import() on one of the modules I can see in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages, I get a NameError: name 'Module' is not defined. Examples that I can see loaded in .../site.packages are pandas, nympy, and PyMySQL. But all give me "name of module not found".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideal python distribution control on a Mac: use a (free) scientific python environment like Enthought or Anaconda, and use either the real virtualenv package or the provided virtualenv package to control 'virtual environments' in which you can install packages.  Virtualenvs really help keep the python distribution clean.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Python development on a Mac can be a pain in the butt. That's why I set up a Arch Linux through Virtual Box and I'm quite happy with it. However, iOS development with Python using Kivy requires XCode (as far as I know) to deploy the apps on the iOS devices. So I'm in the same boot as you are.

Long story short: Running **brew doctor** (as in homebrew) in the terminal helped me a lot cleaning up my Python installations on the Mac.